# How can i customize SetupProgress dialog in installshield?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I want my setup progress window look like Visual Studio's installation's progress window, i.e, show list of features, and show text or image as one by one feature installation completes...!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through a billboard control: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/IHelpEUDialogsBillboard.htm

Basically, you define multiple billboards and configure them to be show during install.

Comment: Actually, i want is to show the list of features\custom actions that i am performing during installation...
So i want a list box and show check marks in front of the features which are installed....
Just like visual studio setup...

Comment: So a custom feature selection dialog. I don't think there is predefined support for this. You may need to create your own dialog which uses custom controls that condition your features.

Comment: yeah, i guess so....
but can i put checkbox or something on SetupProgress Dialog and set its value in my custom action...??

Comment: I don't see how feature selection is related to progress dialog.